# Index of a maximal subgroup in a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

My question is very simple and maybe trivial. Here it is.

Is the index of a maximal subgroup in a finite group always a prime number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a group has the property that all its maximal subgroups have prime index, then it is solvable; this follows from a theorem of P. Hall.

In fact, Hall's theorem reaches that conclusion if the indices are prime or squares of primes. A later theorem of Huppert states that if all of them are prime, the group is supersolvable.

Answer (score 8):

No. The smallest counter-example I can think of is $A_5$, the alternating group on $5$ elements which has order $60$, which has a maximal subgroup of order $10$ and thus index $6$ in $A_5$ (more information can be found [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group%3aA5)).

However, this **does** hold for finite **abelian** groups. To see this, use the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups to write out the abelian group $G$ as $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{e_1}}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_2^{e_2}}\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_n^{e_n}}$. Each maximal subgroup of $G$ contains all of all but one group and a maximal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}$ for some $i$. But the maximal subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}$ are of order $p_i^{e_i - 1}$, so the index of them in $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{e_i}}$ is $p_i$ and thus the index of the maximal subgroup of $G$ is $p_i$ as well.

Comment: That is *the* smallest counterexample, in fact :)

Comment: @Mariano: I realized that when I saw your answer concerning solvability. Which is very interesting, by the way.

Comment: The smallest counterexample is A4, not A5.  The Sylow 3-subgroup has index 4, and 4 isn't prime.

Comment: @Jack: Oh, thanks. I misread Mariano's answer as giving its converse as well.

Answer (score 8):

Thomas, some additional trivial observations: your statement is correct for *normal maximal* subgroups. (However, not true for *maximal normal* (e.g. the identity subgroup is maximal normal in any non-abelian simple group)).
And, if *every* maximal subgroup is normal, this is equivalent to G being nilpotent.

Answer (score 5):

It may be worth remarking that in a finite solvable group $G$, all maximal subgroups have prime power index (there are already examples given in comments of solvable groups with maximal subgroups not of prime index). I am not sure who was the first person to prove this, but it is well-known, and can be found, for example, in D. Gorenstein's
book "Finite Groups" (its proof is elementary compared to many in that book). The proof is as follows: let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. We may suppose that $M$ contains
no nonidentity normal subgroup of $G$ (if $K$ is one such, work in $G/K$). Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then $N$ is an elementary Abelian $q$-group for some prime $q$. Now $N$ is not contained in $M$, so $NM$ is a subgroup of $G$ which strictly contains $M$. Hence $NM = G$. Then $[G:M] = [N:N \cap M]$, and this is a power of $q$.

Note also that if $G$ is a finite solvable group with $\Phi(G) = 1$ and $L$ is any minimal normal subgroup of $G$, then there is a maximal subgroup $H$ of $G$ with 
$[G:H] = |L|$ (this is again well-known). Recall that the Frattini subgroup $\Phi(G)$ is the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$, and is normal. For again, $L$ is an elementary Abelian $q$-group for some prime $q$. Since $\Phi(G) = 1$, there is a maximal subgroup $H$ of $G$ which does not contain $L$. Then $G = LH$. Furthermore, $L \cap H$ is normal in $G$ (since $L$ is Abelian, $L \cap H \lhd L$, and since $L \lhd G$, we also
have $L \cap H \lhd H$). But $L$ is not contained in $H$, so $L \cap H$ is a proper subgroup of $L$. By the minimality of $L$ as a normal subgroup of $G$, we must have 
$L \cap H = 1$, so that $[G:H] = |L|$.