# Center is never a maximal proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that center is not a maximal proper subgroup of group $G$.

Comment: Hint: We can assume that $Z(G)\neq G$. If $x\in G\setminus Z(G)$ what can you say about $C_G(x)$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That needs to be a hint-answer!

Comment: Your edit has made the title and body a bit strange. The term maximal is completely correct in this context (a maximal subgroup is by definition a proper subgroup).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: We can assume that $Z(G)\neq G$. If $x\in G\setminus Z(G)$ what can you say about $C_G(x)$?

Comment: The only thing I know about centralizer is that $|C_G(x)| = |G| / |C(x)|$. But I can't figure out its relationship with Z. Can you tell me more how to tackle this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Do you see that $Z(G)\subseteq C_G(x)$? Do you see that $C_G(x)\neq G$? Do you see an element in $C_G(x)$ which is not in $Z(G)$?

Comment: That is indeed such an element.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different solution, not so easy as the one by Tobias. With the following, the claim follows:

1. If $N \trianglelefteq G$ is a maximal subgroup, then $G/N$ is cyclic of prime order.
2. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Is it really true that maximal subgroups always have prime index?  What is a quick proof?  I know the converse is easily seen to be true (prime index implies maximal).

Comment: @AlexPetzke: No, it is not true in general. For example, in $A_4$ subgroups of order $3$ are maximal of index $4$. But if you have a normal subgroup that is also a maximal subgroup, then it has prime index. This follows with the correspondence theorem. Related questions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/292696/17384) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35427/index-of-a-maximal-subgroup-in-a-finite-group)

Comment: @Mikko: Yes, I figured the normality came into play and that's what I was curious about.  Thanks.